# Smarty nested foreach with associative keys

Tags: php, loops, foreach, smarty, nested-loops

PHP:

```
<?php
$menu = array(
            array('label' => 'myLabel', 'submenu' =>
                array('label' => 'test label',
                    'label' => 'test label',
                    'label' => 'test label'
            )),
            array(...)
        );
 $smarty->assign(array('menu' => $menu));
```

TPL:

```
<ul>        
    {foreach from=$menu key=k item=elem}
    <li>
        <div>
            {$elem.label}
        </div>
        <ul>
            {foreach from=$elem.submenu item=subelem}
                <li>{$subelem.label}</li>
            {/foreach}
        </ul>

    </li>
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```

Note that arrays like `$menu = array(array("A"), array("B"), array("C"));` works fine.

Where am i wrong? Is it possible or smarty is unable to do that?

---

EDIT: Problem is: This output the first list, and the first letter of the first element of the child list in the proper html context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What you did wrong

The inner foreach is where the problem is. Your item (subelem) in the inner foreach is not an array (as you thought), but it's a string.

### Solution

This should work:

```
<ul>        
    {foreach from=$menu key=k item=elem}
    <li>
        <div>
            {$elem.label}
        </div>
        <ul>
            {foreach from=$elem.submenu key=label item=text_label}
                <li>{$text_label}</li>
            {/foreach}
        </ul>

    </li>
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```